# How to pass two filled class models via an Angular http.post 'body' to the controller?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, parameter-passing

I am receiving an error message, "Sequence contains no elements" while trying to update a table in SQL from Angular 7 to an AspNet Core controller by passing two model parameters using an "http.post".

I am passing the data from the form to the class models with no problem because I can see the payload data in the browser console. However, when trying to pass the models as parameters in my api service to the controller, all of the parameters in the model are null. I usually don't have an issue when passing one model parm thru, but passing two of them to get to my controller with a [FromBody] doesn't seem to want to work for me.

I tried to wrap the models in curly brackets to pass them, to no avail:

```
UpdateService(serviceAddress: ServiceAddressModel, contact: ContactModel) {
let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
let body = { svc: serviceAddress, cnt: contact };
reqHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post(this.baseurl + 'api/customermanagement/update-service-address-info', body, { headers: reqHeader });
```

When I view the request / response in the browser console, I can see the data within the payload, so I know that the data is ready to pass.

My controller is set up as follows:

```
       [Route("update-service-address-info")]
    public bool UpdateServiceAddressAccount([FromBody] ServiceAddressEntity svc_id, [FromBody] ContactEntity cnt_id)
    {
        return serviceAddressService.UpdateServiceAddressAccount(svc_id, cnt_id);
    }
```

Using breakpoints in this call shows null for all values.

If I can properly pass the parameters to my interface, I should be good-to-go. I am sensing that I am not structuring the parameters properly in the http.post body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request body, `{ svc: serviceAddress, cnt: contact }` is received as a json string, e.g. `{"svc":{"serviceAddressProperty1":"value",...},"cnt":{"contactProperty1":"value",...}}`. The parameters to your action method are bound via the default model binding mechanism (unless you provide your own custom model binding implementation). The default mechanism attempts to create instances by binding from the top level of the json object received with the request. `enter code here`
In simpler terms, lets assume you class `ServiceAddressModel` is defined like this:

```
public class ServiceAddressModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

the model binder looks for properties with the names `"name"` and `"property2"` at the top level of the json tree. If found, these are bound to the `Name` and `Property2` properties of the created instance.
In your case, wrapping your models in a class that can make `svc_id` and `cnt_id` the top level properties would work fine. Like this example:

```
public class MyRequest
{
     public ServiceAddressModel svc_id { get; set; }
     public ContactEntity cnt_id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can declare your action like

```
 [Route("update-service-address-info")]
public bool UpdateServiceAddressAccount([FromBody] MyRequest request)
{
    return serviceAddressService.UpdateServiceAddressAccount(request.svc_id, request.cnt_id);
}
```

Snake casing, camel casing should be allowed by default (you will have to try it, I havent tested that part). That is, if you declare your properties as `SvcId` and `CntId` (if you prefer more natural C# naming conventions) it should be able to bind correctly from JSONs with `"svc_id"` or `"cnt_id"`.

Another option would be to implement custom model binders, but that might be a longer and more complex route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your method worked like a charm! Also, you're right about the naming convention. It does match up regardless of "case" as long as the spelling is consistent. Kudos!

Comment: @Janou Happy to help. Mind marking as answer if you are satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to pass the value like this and see

let body = { **svc_id**: serviceAddress, **cnt_id**: contact };